# KDE connect can not browse my android phone

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

When I click browse files of KDE connect menu in ubuntu 18.04, it gives me an error and says

```
A folder named /home/asus/.cache/kioexec/krun/7868_0/ already exists
```

what to do?

Comment: delete or rename the folder ?

Comment: I found it easier to install a ftp server on android

Answer (score 1):

Just installing Dolphin worked for me. However, I have been trying to transfer a couple of hundred files from my phone to the PC, but it wasn't very stable - disconnected a without warning and then the devices couldn't find each other until I shutdown  KDEConnect on the PC completely (including kdeconnectd) and re-paired them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under Ubuntu 18.10.

Turns out that "Browse Device" wants to start Dolphin which was not installed.

`sudo apt install dolphin`

Furthermore my installed Dolphin was missing all icons.

I also needed to install qt5ct:

`sudo apt install qt5ct`

and

`sudo apt install oxygen5-icon-theme`

Then set

`echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct" >> ~/.bash_profile` (do not forget to restart your shell)

Afterwards start `qt5ct` and choose 'Oxygen' as icon theme.

Et voilà KDEConnect -> "Browse Device" was working