# KioExec folder already exists, kdeconnect issue

Tags: kde, kde-connect

I found a similar question here, but the answers did not solve my problem.
[KDE connect can not browse my android phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047702/kde-connect-can-not-browse-my-android-phone)

I know how to use a file server in my home. I am not looking for alternatives. Thank you.

When I run kdeinit5 from command and log errors while starting the browse function of kdeconnect I get the following:

```
kdeinit5: Shutting down running client.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/klauncher'
kdeinit5: Launched KLauncher, pid = 5595, result = 0
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
kdeinit5: opened connection to :0
kdeinit5: Got EXT_EXEC '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kioexec' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kioexec'
command= "gnome-software --local-filename=%f" args= ("gnome-software --local-filename=%f", "kdeconnect://0000000000")
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kio_kdeconnect.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kio_kdeconnect.so'
kdeconnect.kio: Setting host:  "000000000"
kdeconnect.kio: Stat:  QUrl("kdeconnect://000000000")
Copying QUrl("kdeconnect://000000000")  to QUrl("file:///home/username/.cache/kioexec/krun/5603_0/")
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/file.so' from launcher.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/file.so'
Aborting aboutToFinish handling.
All files downloaded, will call slotRunApp shortly
No files downloaded -> exiting
kdeinit5: PID 5608 terminated.
kdeinit5: PID 5606 terminated.
kdeinit5: PID 5603 terminated.
```

I just started using kde plasma and I'm not sure if the gnome components are creating the issue. And if so which gnome components are the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kioexec error is now fixed in https://commits.kde.org/kio/3c18acc2229bf0824ee296791329ad74b6313ece

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently still trying to work through the problem and have made some progress. I don't want to redefine the original post because some of the problem is solved. But I still need help.

I made a backup and did something dangerous. I apt-get removed gnome-shell, gnome-desktop3-data, and gdm. Followed that up with:
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
    sudo apt-get autoremove

On reset desktop stuff was real messed up. Pressed CTL+ALT F2
    sudo apt-get install gnome-shell, gnome-desktop3-data, gdm3
install of gdm3 automatically took me to dpkg configuration. I chose gdm3.
Now, pressing the browse phone button works for kdeconnect.

But now I have the issue of when I select a storage folder on the phone I am greeted by an error saying, "The file or folder /run/user/1000/[long number]/storage/[long number]/ does not exist."
Any idea what causes this issue?